# Data from mySQL database delivered in JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I would like to output whole data from database using JSON

Unfortunately i got error on index page, saying: Trying to get property of non-object.. 
I have edited my code and still coming back with error "syntax error, unexpected '$name' ".

```
 <?php
                include_once"model/api.php";

                $text = view_rentalsJSON();
                $adverts = json_decode($text) ;

                for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($adverts); $i++){
                    $staff = $adverts[$i]

                    $name = $staff->name ;
                    echo "Name ".$name."<br/>" ;
                }
 ?
```

This is how my API function look like:

```
function view_rentalsJSON()
{
                include("controller/connection.php");
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
                if ($conn->connect_error) 
                {
                  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }
                $sql = "SELECT * from adverts ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                $array = array();
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $array[] = $row;
                }

                $json = json_encode($array);

                // close connection
                $conn -> close() ;

                //  return the resultant query
                return $json ;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should not encode json manually. Use `json_encode()` for the complete data structure instead.

Comment: Create the *complete* structure you want and then `json_encode` the whole thing. **DO NOT** manually compose it. You'll make mistakes and waste a ton of time fussing over getting it right. Start with `array('stafflist' => array())` and populate it.

Comment: the error   "syntax error, unexpected '$name' "  is only because you did not add semicolon at the end of the line $staff = $adverts[$i]

Comment: Semicolon added. No errors displayed, however still not populating the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- You're not creating JSON string in the *correct way*. Create an empty array `$array` at the beginning, and append `$row` array to this `$array` in each iteration of `while` loop. And after coming out of the loop, use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to encode the resultant array `$array` and return it.
- Your connection handler `$conn` is not available in the scope of your function. Either use `global` or explicitly pass the connection handler to `view_rentalsJSON()` function.
- You need to close the connection before the `return` statement.

So your `view_rentalsJSON()` function should be like this:

```
function view_rentalsJSON($conn){
    $sql = "SELECT * from adverts";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $array = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $array[] = $row;
    }
    $json = json_encode($array);
    $conn->close();

    return $json;
}
```

Subsequently, assuming the fact that `$conn` is your connection handler, you need to change your index page code in the following way,

```
<?php
    include_once"model/api.php";
    $text = view_rentalsJSON($conn);
    $stafflist = json_decode($text);
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($stafflist); $i++){
        $staff = $stafflist[$i] ;

        $name = $staff->name ;
        echo "Name ".$name."<br/>" ;

        //$room = $staff -> room ;
        //echo "Room ".$room."<br/>"  ;

        //$telephone = $staff -> telephone ;
        //echo "telephone ".$telephone."<br/>"  ;
        //echo "<br/>" ;  
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have implemented your solutions, however i have another error on index page.             function view_rentalsJSON()

Comment: @Jack That's probably because there's no property named `name` in `$staff` object(s). Do `var_dump($stafflist);`, paste the output in [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: It works!!!! Absolute massive thank you for your help. Just i have one question to add. How can i get element ID and create link of particular objects? Thats how i would do in PHP, but does it work in JSON?
href='view/review.php?adID=$adID

Comment: @Jack Glad I could help. :-) Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). By the way, to answer your question, assuming the fact that there's an `id` property associated with each object, simply append this id in the link like this: `<a href="view/review.php?adID=<?php echo $staff->id; ?>">your_link</a>`